# Hide warning messages in java

Tags: java, selenium

It is possible to hide the warning messages in java?

Comment: What do you mean by warning messages. The ones in the console ?

Comment: I'm all for NOT hiding warnings. They're there for a reason.

Comment: Yes they are there for a reason, but in my case are useless. I'm running a small java program, that uses selenium with HtmlUnitDriver. And when I run the program, it prints some css warning that doesn't really affect the result I want, so I thought that there is a way to hide them.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to add the details you just posted as comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the warnings printed by the compiler, you could have a look at the [SuppressWarnings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) annotation.